# How do I play these notes from "Zelda's Lullaby"?

Tags: guitar, technique, tablature

How do I play the notes shown in the below image?

[image: guitar tab]

Here's a link of the video if you want to see

It's on minute 02:33

Answer (score 3):

Just as the tab says! Fret 8 bottom string, fret 8 3rd string, fret 7 top string, arpeggiated, from low to high.

Answer (score 1):

Also, in case you can’t tell he is using the second finger on the low E, the third on the G and the first on the high E.